# highlighting smiles features with rdkit

Tags: python-3.x, image, rdkit

```
def drawp4core(mol, feats):
    atoms_list = {}
    for feat in feats:
        atom_ids = feat.GetAtomIds()
        feat_type = feat.GetType()
        atoms_list[feat_type] = atom_ids
    return Draw.MolsToGridImage([mol]*len(atoms_list), highlightAtomLists=list(atoms_list.values()), useSVG=True)

molecule = Chem.MolFromSmiles('C1=NC(=C2C(=N1)N(C=N2)C3C(C(C(O3)CO)O)O)N')
featslists = [featFact.GetFeaturesForMol(molecule) for mol in mols]
drawp4core(molecule, featslists[0])
```

I am trying to highlight pharmacophoric features in small molecules using RDKIT. I have the following code (copied from [ref](https://iwatobipen.wordpress.com/2018/11/27/visualize-pharmacophore-in-rdkit-rdkit/), check it for the full reproducible code).

This works but all the highlights are in separate images like the example. I want them all superimposed in one hopefully in different colours.

[image]

Comment: Did you already try [this](http://rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#highlight-a-substructure-in-a-molecule)?

Comment: No! And this worked!